# MapView navigation movement?

Tags: android

I am trying to make mapView can be moved when navigation movement (when user click device arrow key left, right, up, down).

How to make it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is add the `android:focusable="true"` attribute to your MapView in your layout XML. If you're creating your MapView programmatically, you can make it focusable by calling `mapView.setFocusable(true)`. You can also call `mapView.requestFocus()` if you need to explicitly give the map focus and allow keyboard panning.

You can read more about how the UI framework handles focus in the [Developer Guide section on Handling UI Events](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html#HandlingFocus).